# javascript app preventing csrf

Tags: web-application, csrf, api

I am trying to implement measures against csrf in my client spa.
I have the following question, since it is difficult for me to use the Signed Double-Submit Cookie.
It is possible to implement a csrf preventive measure, where the client generates a random value that it stores in memory, generates a hash of that value,then this hash sends it to an enpoint in the api server that returns a csrf token,
on the server, that value is saved in the session.
Subsequently the client sends the random value initially saved in memory to an endpoint where a state change occurs, and the server generates the hash with this value and compares it with the hash stored in the session, checking if it is not a csrf, since you must be exactly the same...
Is this a good measure?
It is similar to how pkce works with oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This anti-CSRF scheme can be vulnerable to CSRF itself, depending on how exactly the hashed token is exchanged between client and server, and how the client includes the token in subsequent requests.

In the first step of your scheme, the client sends a hash of their generated token to the server, and the server then stores this hash in the session. If the client authenticates through a session cookie, an attacker might be able to perform a CSRF attack before the anti-CSRF protection is in place and set the token to a known value:

1. The attacker generates a token and calculates its hash.
2. Then the attacker tricks the client into visiting an attacker-controlled site. If the session cookie is included in cross-site requests, the attacker can use any site they want, otherwise they have to control or compromise a subdomain of the original site.
3. Through the controlled site, the attacker triggers a request to the CSRF token endpoint, including the hash of the known token as the parameter.
4. This request automatically includes the session cookie, so the server accepts the hash and stores it in the session.
5. Now the attacker has set the client's anti-CSRF token to a known value.

Whether or not the attacker can exploit the known token depends on how exactly the token is sent in subsequent requests. If it's simply a form parameter, then the attacker can again trigger requests which include the known token as a parameter, and the server will accept them -- i.e., a classical CSRF attack.

While the scheme *can* be implemented in a way that is not vulnerable, I strongly recommend using the established, robust and much simpler [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern) instead. You already have server-side state (the session), so the server might as well generate the anti-CSRF token itself and share it with the client, rather than the other way round. This immediately fixes all of the potential vulnerabilities pointed out above. The only reason why alternative schemes like Double-Submit Cookie exist is because some applications do not have server-side sessions at all. Again, this doesn't apply to you.

If, for some reason, you absolutely must implement your scheme, then the server endpoint which initially accepts the token hash cannot rely on cookie-based authentication. Instead, the client must authenticate explicitly through their password or some other secret. This could be combined with the standard log-in procedure: If the client sends the token hash along their password, then the server can assume the hash actually belongs to the client and hasn't been set by an attacker. Additionally, since you're already using JavaScript, consider putting the token in a custom header rather than a form parameter when you make subsequent requests. Attackers on other sites or even subdomains on the same site cannot set custom headers (unless this is explicitly permitted through CORS), so they won't be able to perform CSRF attacks even if they know the token.